# To rewind the tape to where or when?

Tags: figurative-language

When we say **let's rewind the tape to** in a figurative sense, do we use **to when ...** or **to where ...**?

E.g.:

> Let's rewind the tape to when we left.

Or:

> Let's rewind the tape to where we left.

Are both sentences correct and interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically, we nearly always say "where", and "here" to refer to the point in a movie, or on any kind of recording.

- This is **where** we watched up to.
- I've watched the movie up to **here**.

Saying "when", or referring to a measurement of time in some other way, might be used to refer to the *real* time, rather than events in a recording, for example:

- The movie got a bit boring half-way through, that's when we turned it off.

In this example, "when" refers to the actual time that you stopped watching the movie, not the point in the movie.

This is similarly idiomatic with books, where we refer to the "place" in a book we have read to, for example, "*I dropped the book and lost my place*".

Comment: I could imagine playing a tape (or digital equivalent) to someone who says _rewind it to when he says "I've got a gun"_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey agreed, although I can also imagine that same example with "where".

Comment: `Idiomatically, we nearly always say "where", and "here" to refer to the point in a movie, or on any kind of recording.` Thank you for your reply. What would be the correct sentence in my example? Do you use `where` even when referring to the moment of someone's life (figuratively) like e.g.: `Let's rewind the tape to where we were young` or `Let's rewind the tape to when we were young`?

Comment: @tonix that's a somewhat different example - it would be *when* in your life (because that is referring to a point in time, but *where* on the tape (because a tape is a physical thing, and not necessarily a chronological recording.

Comment: @Astralbee Should I use `where` for `tape` even when the tape is used figuratively? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix How do you use "tape" in a figurative sense? What is the tape representing?

Comment: The "tape" in my example represents someone's life or the time. For example, in Italian we say "Riavvolgiamo il nastro", which translated to English would be "Let's rewind the tape" which means e.g. let's talk about what we have talked about before or let's go back and pretend that what just happened didn't happen at all and retry to do something from scratch, etc... The tape here has a figurative connotation and represents time/life. In such cases, to express this meaning, which one would you use: `Let's rewind the tape to when we left` or `Let's rewind the tape to where we left`? Thank you!